# asp mvc Плагин Datatables jQuery При динамическом построении таблицы не ограничивает количество строк

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc, плагин, razor

Если данные статичны все хорошо работает, если я генерирую таблицу с помощью Razor, то вместо 10 строк по умолчанию, выводится весь список. Скрипты добавил в конец представления(Пробовал добавлять и в начало). Буду признателен за любые идеи.

View как пример выглядит вот так. Скрип текущий на данный момент, пробовал и примеры с сайта.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" data-sort-class="filename">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center; " data-field="name" tabindex="0">
                        <div>ИМЯ ФАЙЛА</div>
                        <div class="fht-cell" style="width: 283px;"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; " data-field="name" tabindex="0">
                        <div>ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ</div>
                        <div class="fht-cell" style="width: 283px;"></div>
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; " data-field="name" tabindex="0">
                        <div>ID</div>
                        <div class="fht-cell" style="width: 283px;"></div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@i</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">Somedata</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">Somedata</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        $('#button').click(function () {
            var arr = [];
            $.each(table.rows('.selected').data(), function () {
                var a = this[0];
                arr.push(a.toString());
                table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "POST",
                data: { list: JSON.stringify(arr) },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) { }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: А где в приведенном примере у вас собственно само ограничение?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не задавался этим вопросом, если нарисовать таблицу за ранее то ограничение (Видимо по умолчанию 10 строк)
Вот пример с сайта разработчика
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html
Я к тому что там тоже не задается ограничение.
Не работает и сортировка и поиск, но саму форму рисует(та что в плагине) иными словами на странице все выглядит как положено.

Comment: Т.е. вы утверждаете что нигде в коде (html, css) либо в конфигурационных файлах цифра 10 не должна присутствовать?

Comment: Я могу утверждать только что я плохой программист, а еще если я не правильно написал заголовок, так как не просто 10 строк цель, а еще и его работа -она отсутствует. Прошу Вас, перейдите на сайт с примером.

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема вопроса не решена, но как вариант можно использовать это решение. Я знал об этом решении и раньше, но не знаю JS.

[Ссылка на сайт авторов плагина](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Собственно пример

```
var dataSet = [

[ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
[ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
[ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
[ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
[ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

В dataSet я просто передал массив из контроллера

```
return Json(newList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Верней из скрипта я вызываю контроллер который возвращает данные, и я их как то пытаюсь распарсить

```
<script>

    var d = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Get")',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data,
                    function (key, value) {
                        d.push(value.split(','));
                    });
            }
        });
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({

            data: d,
            columns: [
            { title: "FILENAME" },
            { title: "USERNAME" },
            { title: "ID" }
            ]
        });
        $('#example tbody').on('click',
            'tr',
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
    });
```

ВНИМАНИЕ! Я НЕ ЯВЛЯЮСЬ ПРОГРАММИСТОМ И ПОДОЗРЕВАЮ ЧТО МОЙ ОТВЕТ ЭТО ОЧЕРЕДНОЙ ВЕЛОСИПЕД И ЧТО МОЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ КАК-ТО ЛУЧШЕ.